# Why this Javascript DOM method doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm trying to create a dynamic list, that allows the user to add list/remove list items.

The problem is for some reason

1) 'createTextNode' in this variable doesn't work.
2)

```
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(list ).appendChild(inList);
```

works, while

```
var listContainer = document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(list ).appendChild(inList);
 listCotnainer.appendChild(list).appendChild(inList);
```

DOES NOT!!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Also, would appreciate if you could direct me to a readily written code for the dynamic list, it'll save me a great deal of time. Thanks!

```js
function addItem(txt) {
 var list = document.createElement("li");
 var listAtr = list.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item");
 listAtr.createTextNode(txt);
 
 var inList = document.createElement("button");
 var inListAtr = inList.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
 
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(list ).appendChild(inList);
 //listCotnainer.appendChild(listAtr);
 }

 
 function removeItems() {
   
 }

    
    function removeItem() {
    
    }
```

```html
<section>
    <div ng-controller="addElements">
     <h3>{{subtitle}}</h3>
     <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="addItem('This is a test text')"></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-minus" onclick="removeItems()"></button>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
      <!-- dynamically generate list items here -->
  </ul>
 </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: The `createTextNode` function is a function of the `document` object. It creates a text node and returns a reference to the node. You have to then append that node to the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: When you create a text node, you have to append it, just like when you create an `<li>` node or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `listContainer` is wrong. It should be:

```
var listContainer = document.getElementById("myList");
listCotnainer.appendChild(list).appendChild(inList);
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, I think I duplicated the code when I pasted. It should be like you showed. I have the same in my text editor, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Right code:  
    function addItem(txt) {
 var list = document.createElement("li");
 var listwithTxt = document.createTextNode(txt)
 list.appendChild(listwithTxt);
 
 var listAtr = list.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item");
 
 var inList = document.createElement("button");
 var inListAtr = inList.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
 
 var listContainer= document.getElementById("myList");
 listContainer.appendChild(list).appendChild(inList);
 }